# How to print nth number series in java

Tags: java, series

Could anyone please help me to print below series in java . I am trying to use below code but it seems not working correctly.

Desired output:

---

```
 9  18  27  36  45   
 9  18  27  36   
 9  18  27   
 9  18   
 9
```

---

My code :

```
public class NumberSet {
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        int i = 0, j=0;        
        for (j=1;j<=5;j++)
        {
            for (i=1;i<=50;i++)
            {
                if (i%9 ==0)
                {
                    System.out.print(" " + i + " ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }      
    }
}
```

---

Output of my code:

---

```
 9  18  27  36  45 

 9  18  27  36  45 

 9  18  27  36  45 

 9  18  27  36  45 

 9  18  27  36  45
```

---

Thanks for your help in Advance.

Arfater

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you can generate multiplies of `9` more efficiently by multiplying by `9` than by looping over all numbers and checking if they are divisible by 9.

Second, you can simply change the order of the outer loop, and make the inner loop variable depend on the outer loop variety to get different behavior for every iteration of the outer loop.

```
public class NumberSet {
public static void main (String args[])
{
    int i,j;
    for (j=5;j>=1;j--)
    {
        for (i=1;i<=j;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(" " + i*9 + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
}
```

Output:

```
 9  18  27  36  45 
 9  18  27  36 
 9  18  27 
 9  18 
 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class NumberSet {
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        int i = 0, j=0, mul= 1;        
        for (j=5;j>=1;j--)
        {
           mul = 1;
           for (i=1;i<=j;i++)
           {
              System.out.print(" " + mul++ * 9 + " ");
           }
           System.out.println();
        }      
    }
}
```

Hope this helps u...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
enter code here

public class Myclass {

     public static void main(String args[])

     {
        int num = 5;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++, num--)
        {
          for (int j = 1; j <= num; j++ )
          {
            System.out.print(9*j + " ");
          }
          System.out.println();
        }

      }
}
```